# item listbox (UWP)

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Com esse codigo adiciono itens ao listbosx com a quantidade de registro que tenho. Como ter uma verificação antes para saber se o item daquele registro ja foi adicionada e não aja item com o mesmo none de id?

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (_connection = new teste; Data Source=192.168.0.17;User Id=RFID;Password=1234;SslMode=None;"))
        {
            System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

            _connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id FROM test", _connection);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    listBox.Items.Add(("Registro: " +reader.GetString("id")));


                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (reader.Read())
{


int index = listbox.Items.IndexOf(reader.GetString("id"));
if(index< 0)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(("Registro: " +reader.GetString("id")));
}

}
```

se ele não achar o index quer dizer que não existe então basta adicionar na list, vê se ajuda ^^